# URL redirecting to the same URL

Tags: php, php-5.6

Let's say I have a application hosted on www.example.com, I did a seo check it says that www.example.com redirects to www.exmaple.com

Also to double check i used the below code to check some input params

```
$page = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
echo $page;
```

When I ran the above code on url `www.example.com/about` it returned `about about` twice also when I ran the same code on `www.example.com/some-url-here` it returned `some-url-heresome-url-here` what's the catch? why is the application functioning like this.

Comment: `www.exmaple.com` ... so you've left Canada then?

Comment: You method is probably called twice

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier not sure how could it be called twice? when i am very much aware that i'm calling it once as i have a single page

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Its working fine.. You must be calling it twice for sure.

Comment: i found it somehow it was being called twice, but don't know why it was the error